# Read csv lines and save it as seperate txt file, named as a line - python

Tags: python, csv, readlines

i have some problem with simple code. 
I have a csv file with one column, and hundreds rows. I would like to get a code to read each line of csv and save it as separate txt files. What is important, the txt files should have be named as read line.

Example:
1.Adam
2. Doroty
3. Pablo

will give me adam.txt, doroty.txt and pablo txt. files. Please, help.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Use csv module for reading csv file. CSV module will solve your problem. Check this link https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: You can also use `pandas` which is great to manipulate csv files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find here some help, but this is not a free code writing service...  SO rules requires that you do some research before asking a question, that you show what you have tried and explain where you are stuck. You will find more explainations on what is a correct question at [ask]. You really should read it...

Comment: I have tried something, however I am very begginer

Comment: you can split your problem, 1st learn how to read csv file, 2nd how to iterate file object and 3rd how to write file ( as seperate ). Splitting your problem will help you to learn and explore. If stuck at some point google and browse through atleast 5-6 links.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need on python 3.6

```
with open('file.csv') as f:       # Open file with hundreds of rows 
    for name in f.read().split('\n'):  # Get list of all names
        with open(f'{name.strip()}.txt', 'w') as s:  # Create file per name
            pass
```

Comment: since there is only 1 column you can directly iterate file object `for name in f` I don't think there is need to use `split()`. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You are correct, @akashkarothiya As the file is a .csv, if in fact, the question changes to names on a row ( Daniel, Chris, Jason) this can be easily extended for that use case.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use built-in CSV library to avoid any complications with parsing csv files:

```
import csv
with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        file_name ='{0}.txt'.format(row['first_name'])

        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
            pass
```

Comment: This woroked great, after I customized it for my needs. However, now every time I run it, I got error: KeyError: 'user_name'    I am 100% sure that there is a column with "user_name" in first row. :-(

Comment: if you dont have header row in your csv file, you can initialize reader with default column names: reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,fieldnames=['user_name'])

Comment: just remember in my example i use "first_name" and as per your comment we use "user_name" for column name